# How to fetch the DeptName from table 'DEPARTMENTS' in ZKTeco device

Tags: c#, zkteco

so i have c# api which fetches machinenumber,userid, datetime and checktype. now i have to fetch the 'Deptname' data from table 'DEPARTMENT' and i don't know how to do it. there are 2 ways to get the table name ,the problem is i don't know how to fetch the table name .

[image]

```
public bool SSR_SetDeviceData(int dwMachineNumber, string TableName, string Datas, string Options)
 {
   return objCZKEM.SSR_SetDeviceData(dwMachineNumber, TableName, Datas, Options);
 }

 public bool SSR_GetDeviceData(int dwMachineNumber, out string Buffer, int BufferSize, string TableName, string FiledNames, string Filter, string Options)
 {
    return objCZKEM.SSR_GetDeviceData(dwMachineNumber, out Buffer, BufferSize, TableName, FiledNames, Filter,Options);
 }
```

Comment: If you don't have access to api library then you can't. You need to contact api library team and ask them for the required method.

Answer (score 0):

ZKTeco device´s don´t store information regarding the department or the center, so you can´t retrieve it.

You must perform the match between the device(or employee) and the Department in your solution.